# Temporarily inlay text in Eclipse CEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse plugin. It creates custom Problem markers. What I would like to do is inlay text at the marker location in the CEditor to give the user information. Basically add a comment, but I do not want these comments saved when the user saves the file. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse or is there a plugin that I can use to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. It can be done by treating the editor as a styledText area. With this other controls can be added to the styledText area. I just added a label with my text. Since the label is not part of the actual file it does not get saved with the file. Upon close of the file in the editor the label is disposed and the underlying file is left unmodified by the addition of the label.